# React Native "hidden" screen, multiple screens in one

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Using React Native and React Navigation package, is it possible to connect multiple screens together so when I swipe to the left or right, another screen is visible?

Example, in Instagram the camera screen is hidden until you swipe your finger to reveal it.

Comment: That seems possible to me, but I personally I would use a scrollview with pagination

Comment: Well the camera screen in the instagram app is hidden because of the tab based navigation system. So you could go with a similar approach and implement a tab navigation